# Opencart - how do i add submenu in admin panel

Tags: opencart

I want to add a **sub-menu** in `Opencart` admin panel .

I was saw this [link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=45566), but it didn't really help .

any help will be appropriated .

Comment: Hi @Jake konz...I need to create menu links in admin panel header....
just I want to edit my href links in some menu in header..Is it possible in core or VQMOD?can u please explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just find it out and here the solution :

because we should not modify the core and only solution is VQMOD , you should add some line to your xml file witch there is in xml folder :

```
<file name="admin/controller/common/header.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_backup'] = $this->language->get('text_backup');]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[      $this->data['text_export'] = "sms";]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->data['backup'] = $this->url->link('tool/backup', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[          $this->data['export'] = $this->url->link('tool/export', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

it add menu to system menu .
Hope it Helps.